# How R handle small numbers?

Tags: r, floating-point, fractions

I was trying a small basic code on how R handles small numbers as shown below. I know that for fractions which cannot be represented internally, the computer rounds off to the near approximate value.

I tried computing **(1+ex1-1)** by assigning ex1 from 10<sup>-1</sup> to 10<sup>-11</sup> and each time I got ex1 as output which was right. But assigning ex1 from 10<sup>-12</sup> and there on, the output seems to be wrong. For the second case, I am still wondering why the output is not same as ex1.

```
> ex1 <- 10^-11
> (1+ex1)-1
[1] 1e-11

> ex1 <- 10^-12
> (1+ex1)-1
[1] 1.000089e-12
```

I tried looking at the other stack answer but couldn't find one. This might be duplicate but I am looking for an answer or at least a hint.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Your code is very hard to read. Please put spaces *at least*  around `<-`.